# Passing longitude and latitude into Google maps initialize function

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to pass a longitude and latitude to Google Maps JavaScript V3 api. My code as below should take the googleLatLong variable from the switch and then pass it to the Google initialize() function. However at the moment the googleLatLong variable is not accessible in the initialize() function. How do I pass it through?

Thanks in advance.

JavaScript in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//function to get a parameter from the query string
var queryString = function(){
  var s = window.location.search.substr(1),
      p = s.split(/\&/),
      l = p.length, 
      kv, r = {};
  if(l === 0){return false;}
    while(l--){
      kv = p[l].split(/\=/);
      r[kv[0]] = kv[1] || true;
    }
    return r;
}();

//get params from the url
var storeCode = queryString.store;

//switch page params based on the store code
switch(storeCode) {
    case 'POO746':
        var storeName = 'Poole';
        var googleLatLong = '50.736129,-1.988229';
        var trafficURL = 'http://hatrafficinfo.dft.gov.uk/feeds/rss/CurrentAndFutureEvents/South%20West.xml';
        break;
    case 'BRS464':
        var storeName = 'Bognor Regis';
        var googleLatLong = '50.798991,-0.667444';
        var trafficURL = 'http://hatrafficinfo.dft.gov.uk/feeds/rss/CurrentAndFutureEvents/South%20East.xml';
        break;
}    

</script>
```

JavaScript in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map

function initialize() {
    var store = new google.maps.LatLng(googleLatLong);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: store
    }   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);

}

window.onload = function () {
    initialize();
}
</script>


    <div id="trafficMap">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed this in the end, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this in the end by splitting out the longitude and lattitude. Creating seperate vars for longitude and latitude. Instead of

```
 var googleLatLong = '50.736129,-1.988229';
```

I now have:

```
 var glat = '50.736129';
 var glong = '-1.988229';
```

and in the Google Maps initialize function it now looks like this:

```
 var store = new google.maps.LatLng(glat,glong);
```

Not really sure why it wasn't working with the combined longitude and latitude variable but there you go, making this change made the code work.

Answer (score 0):

Make it global to the page, so you'll have these globals:

```
var storeCode = queryString.store;
var googleLatLong;
var map;
```

Comment: When you say make it global to the page, where do you mean I put this? I tried putting it next to var map and it doesn't seem to make the map show up.

Comment: Put it outside of any function.  Then it is accessible by all functions (as long as the function doesn't declare a variable of the same name which would effectively hide the global one).   Also, make sure the value is assigned before an attempt is made to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the query string in your initialize function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map

  //function to get a parameter from the query string
  var queryString = function(){
    var s = window.location.search.substr(1),
      p = s.split(/\&/),
      l = p.length, 
      kv, r = {};
    if(l === 0){return false;}
      while(l--){
        kv = p[l].split(/\=/);
        r[kv[0]] = kv[1] || true;
      }
      return r;
  }();

function initialize() {


//get params from the url
var storeCode = queryString.store;

//switch page params based on the store code
switch(storeCode) {
    case 'POO746':
        var storeName = 'Poole';
        var googleLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(50.736129,-1.988229);
        var trafficURL = 'http://hatrafficinfo.dft.gov.uk/feeds/rss/CurrentAndFutureEvents/South%20West.xml';
        break;
    case 'BRS464':
        var storeName = 'Bognor Regis';
        var googleLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(50.798991,-0.667444);
        var trafficURL = 'http://hatrafficinfo.dft.gov.uk/feeds/rss/CurrentAndFutureEvents/South%20East.xml';
        break;
}




    var store = googleLatLong;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: store
    }   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);

}

window.onload = function () {
    initialize();
}
</script>
```

- [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomap.html?lat=0.884976&lng=-81.018677&zoom=7&type=m)
- [Example with your code/BRS464](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_parseQueryOnInit.html?store=BRS464)
- [Example with your code/POO746](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_parseQueryOnInit.html?store=POO746)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?  I didn't test that code, just modified yours, have you checked the javascript console?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you had changed the code. Which parts did you change?

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I try this code the map still doesn't show and then I have another failure on the page as trafficURL is then undefined when used furthur down the page.

Comment: There were 2 issues in the posted code that I just fixed.  googleLatLong is a string, it needs to be a google.maps.LatLng.  Since it is already a google.maps.LatLng, store is just a copy of it.